# Powershell Script to fill the Description field

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, windows-scripting

I been searching for help in compiling a script that I can manually run (not as a logon script) that will query every computer account in a particular OU, grab current/last logged on user, user display name, IP, system manufacturer and model number, BIOS serial/dell service tag.

Something to look like this:

**user | user display name | IP address | Dell Optiplex 3050 | 1ASDFG5**

Code i'm trying to use is the one below, but I need more help getting the rest of the fields and compiling it in the format above

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -searchBase "OU=workstations,OU=workstation,DC=mydomain,DC=local"
foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
$vendor = (Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $computer.Name Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).Vendor
$name = (Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $computer.Name Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).Name
$identifyingNumber = (Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $computer.Name Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).IdentifyingNumber
$vendor
$name
$identifyingNumber
Set-ADComputer $computer –Description “$vendor | $name | $identifyingNumber”
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be better achieved as part of a process that runs in the user's context in a distributed fashion as part of something *such as a logon script* or as simply another triggered task (such as a scheduled task that runs on logon so as to keep the information up to date).

Then when implementing something like that, you can gather the details you require in the said script and post it back to the computer AD object. Once there, your query no longer requires the device to be online, nor will it be a long running script.

Here's an example script of what you could deploy to run on computers:

```
# Function to Set Value on Computer Object
function Set-ADComputerObj
{
    Param ( $ComputerID, $PropertyName, $Value )

    $ComputerSearcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
    $ComputerSearcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$("DC=$(($ENV:USERDNSDOMAIN).Replace(".",",DC="))")"
    $ComputerSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(CN=$ComputerID))"

    $computerObj = [ADSI]$ComputerSearcher.FindOne().Path

    $computerObj.Put( $PropertyName, $Value ) 
    $computerObj.SetInfo()

}

# Function to Get Values from User Object
function Get-ADUserObj
{
    Param ( [string]$Identity = $env:USERNAME )
    IF ($Identity)
    {

        $UserSearcher = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
        $UserSearcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$("DC=$(($ENV:USERDNSDOMAIN).Replace(".",",DC="))")"
        $UserSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(SAMAccountName=$Identity))"

        $UserSearcher.FindOne() | foreach {New-Object PSObject -Property:$_.Properties}
    }
}

#===================================

# SAMAccountName for computer object
$ComputerID = $env:COMPUTERNAME

# SAMAccountName for user object
$UserID = $env:USERNAME

# User AD object
$UserObj = Get-ADUserObj

# Display Name for the current user
$UserDisplayName = $UserObj.displayname

# Get LAN IP Address (may need to be modified to account for multiple adapters)
$IPAddress = (Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias ((Get-NetAdapter | where {$_.Status -eq "Up" -and ($_.HardwareInterface -eq $true)}).Name) | where {$_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4"}).IPAddress

# Get Asset Product Details
$Asset = (Get-WMIObject -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME Win32_ComputerSystemProduct)
$AssetVendor = $Asset.Vendor
$AssetName = $Asset.Name
$AssetNumber = $Asset.IdentifyingNumber

# Set Parameter Values for the Set Command on Computer Object
$ComputerObjProperty = "description"
$ComputerObjValue = "$UserID|$UserDisplayName|$IPAddress|$ProductVendor|$ProductName|$ProductNumber"

#===================================

Try
{
    # Set Value on Computer Object
    Set-ADComputerObj -ComputerID $ComputerID -PropertyName $ComputerObjProperty -Value $ComputerObjValue
}
Catch
{
    # Write error exception
    $error[0].Exception
}
```

What this script will then do is create the string you have asked for, and place it on the description of the AD computer object. From there, you can retrieve the description field and split it by the separating character.

For example:

```
$UserID,$UserDisplayName,$IPAddress,$ProductVendor,$ProductName,$ProductNumber = ((Get-ADComputer $ComputerName).description).split("|")
```

Ultimately this could be used to deliver what you're looking to do.